# How to parse "in the twenties"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, proper-nouns

In the following sentence:

> Movies with sound became popular in the twenties

how would I parse the prep phrase? Mainly I can't figure out part of speech of "twenties". Is it a common noun or proper noun?

Or, if it were written as follows:

> Movies with sound became popular after 1925

is "after 1925" also a prep phrase? And what would be the part of speech of 1925?

Answer (score 1):

"Twenties" is a common noun and the object of the prepositional phrase "in the twenties." In the other sentence, 1925 is also a noun and the object of the prepositional phrase "after 1925."

Answer (score 1):

Both *twenties* and *1925* are nouns; periods of time, specifically. And they are also both objects of prepositions: *in* and *after*, respectively.

There are two general rules of English you can follow to figure out that these are nouns. First, the definition of noun: *person, place, or thing*, generally speaking. Dates and times are *things*. Second, the use of prepositions, which require a noun target. *In* what? The *twenties*. *After* what? *1925*.

> Is it a common noun or proper noun?

These are both common nouns. *Twenties* refers to a general group of numbers with two as the tens digit. Because it doesn't refer to anything specific, it cannot be a proper noun.

Even though 1925 refers to a specific year, it's still a common noun, because it's a number. Numbers just aren't proper nouns in English, even though there's only one specific year in this case, because *1925* can be used in a broad range of contexts and mean subtly different things, depending on the context. A year, an age, a count, the result of a calculation, etc.